# Get a url for an action in GSP?

Tags: grails, gsp

How can I get the url (not the link) to an action in gsp?  The `<g:link>` tag gives a link, but I need the url for an ajax post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`<g:createLink>`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html)